# Temporaries in member functions - C++

Tags: c++

After putting some code to work, I'm trying to optimize it. One thing that I'm trying to avoid is the creation of temporaries. Given a class

```
class foo{
   private:
     int a;
   public:
     foo(int sa):a(sa);
     ~foo(){}
    inline int multiply(int b) {return a*b;}//temporary?
};
```

The intel compiler is giving me the temporary created/reference temporary used here. Is any temporary variable being created?

EDIT: edited the return type. Also, I *think* that no temporary variable is being created in multiply, but the intel compiler gives me an error about that.

EDIT 2: After the requests below, here is a FULL code that the intel compiler v. 12 gives the error:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <complex>

 using namespace std;
 const double pi = 3.1415;
 const complex <double> I = (0.0,I);
 const complex <double> oneover2piI = (1.0 / (2.0 * pi * I));

  class foo{
     private:
       complex <double> a;
     public:
       foo(complex <double> sa):a(sa){}
       ~foo(){}
       inline complex <double> multiply(complex<double> b) 
       {return  a*sqrt(b);}
   };
```

The compilation line is

```
  icc -g -O2 -w2 -debug parallel -Wcheck -Weffc++ -mp -fp-stack-check -wd981 -wd2015 -wd1418  test.cpp -o  test
```

And the resulting warning is

```
  test.cpp(7): remark #383: value copied to temporary, reference to temporary used
  const complex <double> oneover2piI = (1.0 / (2.0 * pi * I));
                                         ^
```

The question was to *understand* what the compiler is balking at, and not to be hanous.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious: Where's the return type? Is it inferred?

Comment: Did you intend to write `inline int multiply(int b)`? Other than that, no optimization necessary. You're dealing with intrinsic types, so it'll all be done in registers.

Comment: My bet is that they tried to write `inline int& multiply(int b)` or some equally hanous thing to "optimize" their code.  Otherwise the mention of 'reference' in the sentence that doesn't make any sense, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That^ is actually a really good point; I didn't notice it. If that's the case, be aware that that's not even allowed, because you can't return a reference to a stack-based variable that's destroyed by the end of the function!

Comment: OK, cool.  Now the question makes 0 sense given the lame description of the compiler's output.

Comment: You're not telling us something here. You're either not showing us the actual code you're using, or the error message is related to something completely different.

Comment: The error message: remark #383: value copied to temporary, reference to temporary used - and this is not the actual code. If needed I can post the offending code.

Comment: @Ivan - That code did not give you that error.  Nothing resembling it did either.

Comment: It is needed. How are we supposed to help you with your code if you're posting different code?

Comment: @Noah OK then, what did you mean when you wrote hanous?

Comment: Actually I was more interested in the relation between the error on the compiler and this _kind_ of code, not exactly with help on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the compiler issues a warning because it translates:

```
const complex <double> oneover2piI = (1.0 / (2.0 * pi * I));
```

to invoke a default copy constructor:

```
Object::complex<double>(const complex<double>&)
```

which takes a reference of the temporary object as the argument, and makes a shallow copy (that results in data sharing if you use pointers) of the object. Basically this data sharing + temporary lifespan is the core of the problem. Take a look at the "academic" class below.

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{

public:

  A()
    :attribute(new char[10]) {}

  ~A()
  {
    std::cout << "d'ctor" << std::endl; 
    if(attribute){
      delete [] attribute;
      attribute = 0;
    }
  }

  A& operator +(const char& n)
  {
    //do some operation
    return *this;
  }

  void reset_attribute(char *new_ptr)
  {
    attribute = new_ptr;
  }

private:

  char *attribute;
};

int main()
{
  {//new scope to invoke destructors
    A b;
    A c = b;
    b.reset_attribute(new char[10]);
  }//no problem in this scope

  A a = (A()+2);//problem with a temporary object

  return 0;
}
```

the *cygwin* output:

```
$ ./a.exe
d'ctor //this is from b or c
d'ctor //this is from b or c
d'ctor //this is from temporary
d'ctor //this is from a
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The `delete` operation has been executed twice on the same pointer, because it was shared between the temporary object and *a*.

Answer (score 4):

***Don't worry about it.***

What you are doing is called "premature micro-optimization," and it is the [root of much evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211414/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

It is also largely futile to try to micro-optimize

1. micro-optimization without first profiling your code and identifying the places that need to be optimized is a complete waste of time.  You *might* end up shaving picoseconds off a routine that takes millions of picoseconds.  Why bother?
2. The compiler will optimize you code far better than you can.  MicroSoft for example has a team of people whose only job is to work on the optimizer.  They are very smart people, working all day every day finding ways to optimize your code. In this case, the temporaries will often be optimized away. Let them do their thing.  They are better at it than you.
3. micro-optimizations often come at the cost of harder to understand code.  Code that is harder to understand is much more prone to having defects.  Those 4 picoseconds you saved are worthless if your function returns "fA@#zzzzzzz" instead of "foo".

First, select the correct algorithms for your task.  Then write good, robust code that implements those algorithms.  Profile in release mode second.  Guided by the profiler, find the places that *really* need to be optimized, if there are any.  Then optimize.

Comment: The code is already written, and it's readable. I'm profiling it, and this was one of the ideas that I've had to try to improve performance. The case above is just an example. But thanks for your input! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question (I'm not sure where the temporary variable is created myself), but in general, creating temporary primitive variables will not save *any* speed, because the only difference is the stack space used -- so whether the stack pointer is incremented by 4 bytes or 8 bytes is irrelevant to the speed of your program, unless there's a page fault (which is very unlikely). So you're unlikely to see any performance benefits with anything like this, especially if the compiler optimizes your code by putting variables in registers.

Answer (score 0):

`a*b` creates a new temporary.  Whatever the hell the rest of your question text means, I have no idea, but in as far as you use the word "temporary", one is created.

Given the code you claim the compiler is complaining about...the compiler should not be complaining.  Since you've not included the real error...I have absolutely no clue why you think it's complaining about what you claim its complaining about.

Edit:

Given that you claim the code in your edit is the REAL code causing the error you also finally quoted, my bet is that the compiler has been completely confused by the line BEFORE the one it's complaining about:

```
const complex <double> I = (0.0,I);
```

I don't know what you indend for that to do, but it don't look legal to me.